# Why my Highlight.js dosen't work correctly?

Tags: syntax, npm, highlight.js

I don't know how https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/ work.

I had install highlight.js by npm

`npm install highlight.js`

and I use

`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='path/to/zenburn.css' />`

and

`<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/highlight.js'></scrpit>`

and

`<script> h1js.initHighlightingOnload(); </script>`

and I also wrap my 'java source code' in `<pre><code class='java'>......</code></pre>`

this is the screenshot [Java source code is not highlighted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d4UP.jpg)

I had notice that the F12 of the Highlight.js's website demo , shows that the output of java code is wrapped in `<span>...</span>`, how can I do to correctly display the highlighted code.

Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the sample paths shown in your question above to the correct paths for your application (such as 'node_modules/highlight.js/build/styles/zenburn.css')? Also note, in some scenarios you may have to build the highlight.js package before you can use it. More detailed information can be found [here](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).